# How to create Bar Chart with the data provided | EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to create a bar chart using the following data,

```
Name           Number
221300290       45
N5231690        655
04178290        550
02350090        185
1002131690      335
00362132189     44
N473213990      385
01903190        30
C255090         50
02142590        54
01794590        740
```

When i try to insert a clustered bar chart, i get weird image. I guess its because of the column names under "Name". Because when i change the names under it to for eg: A, B, C, etc. I get a proper bar chart.

Is there any way to create a bar graph for this data?

Comment: @yass gave you a great answer for a bar chart. If you're looking to create a clustered bar chart (indicated in your question), you're going to need something that tells the clustered chart how to group the data. Categories, Quarters, Months, etc. There may be another way to do it, but adding a helper/third column with assigned groups to your entries should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only one column to create the Bar Chart, Select the Number column and create the Chart, then select the Chart and under Chart Tools Design, click on Select Data then under Horizontal category axes, click Edit select the Data under Name and click Ok.

[image]